# append to xml without overwrite data

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I just started to learn xml, and I have task for now, to get data from php submitted form and write this to xml file. I have function in class for now that write data to xml file after form submitted and it looks like this

```
function writeFile () {
    $dom = new DomDocument('1.0');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    if( $xml = file_get_contents( 'include/users.xml') ) {
        $dom->loadXML( $xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS );

         // find the headercontent tag
        $users = $dom->getElementsByTagName('users')->item(0);

        // добавление корня - <users> 
        //$users = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('users')); 
        $user = $users->appendChild($dom->createElement('user'));
        $xml_name = $user->appendChild($dom->createElement('name'));
        $xml_name->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($this->name));
        $xml_email = $user->appendChild($dom->createElement('mail'));
        $xml_email->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($this->email));

        // add the user tag before the first element in the <users> tag
        $users->insertBefore( $user, $users->firstChild );

        $dom->save('include/users.xml');
    }
}
```

Then on my users.xml I have:

```
<users>
  <user>
    <name>User1</name>
    <mail>new2@mail.ru</mail>
  </user>
</users>
```

But my problem is that my `<user>` data all the time overwrites instead of append new user like:

```
<users>
  <user>
    <name>User1</name>
    <mail>new2@gmail.com</mail>
  </user>
  <user>
    <name>User2</name>
    <mail>new3@gmail.com</mail>
  </user>
</users>
```

I'll be grateful for any help

Comment: Well, load the saved document if it exists, validate that the document element exists and append the new user elements to it.

Comment: Update my code, found mistake, as I see now it's working.

Comment: You don't need to search for the `users` element. It is available in `$dom->documentElement`.